# Sorting unique vectors in c

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, vector

The program should eliminate any repeating digits and sort the remaining ones in ascending order. I know how to print unique digits but I don´t know how to create a new vector from them that i can later sort.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void unique(double arr[], int n) {
    int i, j, k;
    int ctr = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("element - %d : ",i);
        scanf("%lf", &arr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ctr = 0;

        for (j = 0, k = n; j < k + 1; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    ctr++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (ctr == 0) {
            printf("%f ",arr[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    double arr[100];
    int n;
    printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    unique(arr, n);
}
```

Comment: Using a loop? Like `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", &arr[i]);`. That's most basic knowledge.

Comment: Do you mean sort the unique values? Insert them in a tree?

Comment: What I´m trying to do is create a new vector from the unique digits

Comment: Can you provide a small example of what you mean?

Comment: Yes of course sorry if what I´m saying is confusing I´m not really great at programing. So basically I want to create a program in which you insert a vector for example {1,2,6,2,3,2,5,3} and the program should find the unique digits (meaning it should remove the repeating digits) so we would be left with {1,2,6,3,5} and then it should sort it in ascending order so we get {1,2,3,5,6} (or maybe it would be even simpler to sort it first and then remove the repeating digits)

Comment: Aside: Be wary of this: `j < k + 1`. Since `k = n`, then the last valid index to use  for the array is `k - 1`.  `j < k + 1` ensures you use `k` as an index. This is an [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error, and will invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) when it reads an uninitialized value, or past the end of the array.

Comment: Because of the symmetric nature of equality, all numbers are checked twice, once in reverse; `for(j = 0; j < i; j++)` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can always break a larger problem down into smaller parts.

First create a function that checks if a value already exists in an array.

Then create a function that fills your array with values. Check if the value is in the array before adding it. If it is, you skip it.

Then create a function that sorts an array. Alternatively, [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) is a library function commonly used to sort arrays.

This is far from efficient, but should be fairly easy to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NUMS 256

int find(double *arr, size_t length, double val)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (val == arr[i])
            return 1;

    return 0;
}

size_t fill_with_uniques(double *arr, size_t limit)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    size_t len = 0;

    while (n < limit) {
        double value;

        printf("Enter value #%zu: ", n + 1);

        if (1 != scanf("%lf", &value))
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        /* if value is not already in the array, add it */
        if (!find(arr, len, value))
            arr[len++] = value;

        n++;
    }

    return len;
}

int compare(const void *va, const void *vb)
{
    double a = *(const double *) va;
    double b = *(const double *) vb;

    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

int main(void)
{
    double array[MAX_NUMS];
    size_t count;

    printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: ");

    if (1 != scanf("%zu", &count))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (count > MAX_NUMS)
        count = MAX_NUMS;

    size_t length = fill_with_uniques(array, count);

    /* sort the array */
    qsort(array, length, sizeof *array, compare);

    /* print the array */
    printf("[ ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%.1f ", array[i]);
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Above we read values from `stdin`. Alternatively, `fill_with_uniques` could take two arrays, a `source` and a `destination`, and copy values from the former into the latter, only when they would be unique.

Remember to never ignore the return value of `scanf`, which is the number of successful *conversions* that occurred (in other words, variables assigned values). Otherwise, if the user enters something unexpected, your program may operate on indeterminate values.